# Integer-of-date, command window, libraries

Tags: cobol

I'm learning about cobol alone and when I was coding my first code I had some doubts.

I'm using GnuCOBOL v2.2 at websites (TutorialsPoint and JDoodle) and I didn't understand how I can put inputs by comand window. Do anyone know how do it at these websites ?

Other thing is about how to clean terminal, when I use "DISPLAY WINDOW ERASE" I have that error message: "140: warning: GRAPHICAL WINDOW is not implemented". Do I need to use any library or exist any other comand ?

One more doubt: function integer-of-date do not convert that it proposes, the output is coming zero just. Code is below:

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
77 DATA1 PIC 9(006). 
77 DATA2 PIC 9(006).
77 INTEIRO-1 PIC 9(008).
77 INTEIRO-2 PIC 9(008).
77 DIAS PIC 9(005).


PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
ACCEPT DATA1 FROM DATE
SET DATA2 TO 930217
MOVE FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DATE (DATA1) TO INTEIRO-1 *> wrong convertion?
MOVE FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DATE (DATA2) TO INTEIRO-2
COMPUTE DIAS = INTEIRO-2 - INTEIRO-1
DISPLAY X"0A"DATA1 " " DATA2
SET INTEIRO-1 TO FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DATE(DATA1)
DISPLAY INTEIRO-1 " " INTEIRO-2
DISPLAY "DIAS: " DIAS
```

The output of that code is:

```
180516 930217
00000000 00000000
DIAS: 00000
```

Comment: You've asked three clearly different questions in this single post. This is a *question* and answer site, not a *here's a list of my questions* site. If you have multiple separate questions, create multiple posts for each one.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will do that at next post

Comment: @HumbertoFialho - I suggest to do so now and I have at least two answers for you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the integer-of-date question

`FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DATE(ccyymmdd)`

You need to use full 4 digit years in a `PIC 9(8)` field for this function.

`ACCEPT FROM DATE` returns a `PIC 9(6)`, and there is now an
`ACCEPT FROM DATE YYYYMMDD` form that returns a `PIC 9(8)`.

Comment: Perfect answer ! That corrected the problem about how to calculate a date period

Answer (score 1):

1. The `INTEGER-OF-DATE()` intrinsic function takes a date in 8 digits format (YYYYMMDD). You could use `FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE` to get an 8 digit date.
2. The syntax `SET datum TO value` is normally reserved for indices, for general data you should use `MOVE value TO datum`.